# How numpy decides number of coefficient in smooth bivariate spline?

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, interpolation

I am using SmoothBivariateSpline of numpy library to get a surface fit of a data.

By default degrees of bivariate spline is 3. When i am fitting my data, if the degree is 3, i should get 16 coefficients and 8 knot points in x and y direction respectively. This is happening for one of the spline fit (f1). But i am getting 25 coefficients and 9 knot points for the second fit (f2).

Can someone please tell me why i am getting more number of coefficients?? if you want i can share my data file as well.

here is my code

```
import numpy as np
# loading the txt file from where i am reading data
L = np.loadtxt('DATA_File_PT.txt')

P = L[:,0]  # pressure
T = L[:,1]  # temperature
H = L[:,2]  # enthalpy
Rho = L[:,3] # density


# fitting Spline for each set (I have P and T as independent variable, H and Rho are dependent)

f1 = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(P, T, H, kx=3, ky=3)
f2 = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(P, T, Rho, kx=3, ky=3)

o1=f1.get_knots()
coeff1 = f1.get_coeffs()

o2=f2.get_knots()
coeff2 = f2.get_coeffs()
```

Comment: SmoothBivariateSpline is in the SciPy library, not NumPy.  Without the data it is hard to tell what is going on. However, to get a smooth fit the underlying numerical method can decide it needs more knots (based eps which you left as a default). So Rho is likely less well behaved (smooth) than H and scipy wanted more knots to give you a smooth surface.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for your valuable inputs. I was just curious if there is a way to fix the number of coefficients and knot points. I thought that if i choose "kx=3 and ky=3" i will get a cubical surface fit with fixed number of coefficients and knot points irrespective of the accuracy. To get less number of coefficients and knot points I tried varaying "eps" but any value of the order of >=10^-2 is giving 25 coefficients and less than that is giving 16 coefficients but highly inaccurate results. Can you tell me any other way to tackle this?

Comment: well, you could play with the procedural (older) scipy.interpolate.bisplrep function - it takes more parameters but likely has the same code under the hood.  I'll note that one of the parameters to bisplrep() is 'Over-estimates of the total number of knots' indicating to me that it is fairly normal to return more knots than you seem to expect. To fit a cubic surface you might instead consider something like scipy.optimize.root to explicitly fit the points to a desired function form.